# Text Messaging my business location when someone enters their zip code

Tags: php

When a customer enters their zip code as text message and text it as "my company name", they get the nearest location. how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Be nice.  English isn't this person's first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is pertinent to what you're asking, but: if you're interested in checking out a great RESTful API for adding SMS and voice to your apps, you might start with [twilio](http://www.twilio.com). You can use their API for things like checking zip codes upon SMS receipt; with that type of handling in place, you could react properly in your app.

Answer (score 0):

[phpDealer Locator](http://www.yourphppro.com/version/en-us/content/page_4.html), may do what you need it to. Otherwise, you will need to reword question to provide us with a better understanding of what it is you really want.